# In formal English can we replace and with ","?

Tags: conjunctions

In formal English can we replace **and** with ","?

> Traditional UK food is fish and chips **and** roast beef **and** roast potatoes with Yorkshire pudding.

Can we re-write it as following:

> Traditional UK food is fish and chips, roast beef **and** roast potatoes with Yorkshire pudding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least 3 items in a list to use a comma.  The last two are separated by *and*.

> X, Y and Z.
>
> W, X, Y and Z.

etc.

If you only have 2 items in a list, only *and* is used.

> X and Y.

It's possible for an item in a list to itself be "X and Y".  This is awkward but you would not necessarily change the commas based on that - but you can offset the second-to-last item with a comma if you have 3 or more items in the list.

> The two things I like to eat most are fish and chips and chips and salsa.
>
> The three color combinations I like are red and blue, red and white, and white and black.

You're better off using an actual list headered by a colon and separated by a semicolon if one of your items has three "sub-items"

> I like the following color combinations: red and blue; red, white and green; and black and white.